# How to install Chef knife-ec2 plugin on Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install the Chef knife-ec2 plugin on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1 x64bit.
Chefdk 0.4.0 installs successfully and I can use the `knife` command without any issues.

I can install the knife-ec2 plugin without any errors by using the following command:
`/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install knife-ec2`

However, once installed there seems to be a conflict with the `fog` gem. I get the following error when attempting to run any `knife` commands:

```
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2104:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate knife-ec2-0.10.0, because fog-1.27.0 conflicts with fog (~> 1.23.0) (Gem::ConflictError)
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1282:in `activate'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:198:in `rescue in try_activate'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:195:in `try_activate'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `rescue in require'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
from /home/umar/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/knife-ec2-0.10.0/lib/chef/knife/ec2_server_list.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:35:in `load'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:35:in `block in load_commands'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:35:in `each'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:35:in `load_commands'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/knife.rb:126:in `load_commands'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/knife.rb:207:in `run'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:139:in `run'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.0.3/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/knife:23:in `load'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/knife:23:in `<main>'
```

My Path variable, if it makes any difference, is as follows:
`/home/ubuntuuser/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin:/opt/chefdk/bin:/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

I've gotten this to work successfully on another VM running the exact same OS, chefkdk and knife plugins. I didn't document the steps I took since it seemed to be pretty straightforward. Now I'm pulling my hair out trying to set it up again.

This is all on a VM and I have several snapshots along the way. So if instead of resolving the conflict issue, someone can give me correct steps on how to install the knife-ec2 plug, that would be just as good.

Comment: Note: I'm still just starting to learn about ubuntu, chef, and ruby so I'm having a difficult time removing the conflicts. Please keep in mind if possible when suggesting solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit the same error.  This sort of counts as resolving the conflict error.  I hope it's a temporary solution and that fog just gets into compliance, or whatever.  My workaround was to install fog 1.23.0 explicitly and uninstall 1.27.0.

```
chef gem install fog -v '1.23.0'
chef gem uninstall fog -v '1.27.0'
```

Technically, I had to `sudo` to uninstall.  A more curious person might wonder at the asymmetry of it, and I'm somewhat suspicious that I did something more global than I meant to.  But I was mostly happy to get the thing working.  There's a [changelog for fog](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/639c5e348a5ea8757c8ea1cae1af151d063130c7/CHANGELOG.md) in case I ever get around to worrying about that.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. Nothing else seems to be broken for now although it seems odd that such a conflict would exist.